# ifthen and spreadtab

Tags: xifthen, spreadtab

I use the `spreadtab` and the `xifthen` packages for computing percentiles, but I found an unusual behavior. I give an example of false result: a true command remains false when it's used in a spreadtab. The  command

```
\ifthenelse{\isodd{19}\and\isodd{21}}{True}{False}
```

which is true is given as false in this tabular:

```
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|}}
 \hline 
    19  &   21  
\\ \hline
\ifthenelse{\isodd{:={[0,-1]}}\and\isodd{:={[1,-1]}}}{True}{False}  
&               
\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}
```

What is the reason of this and how can I remain to it ? I give here an example, where one can see that the test has a good result outside the tabular

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab} 
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|}}
 \hline 
    19  &   21  
\\ \hline
\ifthenelse{\isodd{:={[0,-1]}}\and\isodd{:={[1,-1]}}}{True}{False}  
&               
\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}

\ifthenelse{\isodd{19}\and\isodd{21}}{True}{False}
\end{document}
```

From the answer of 'jfbu', I saw that this depends on the test used, and gives the original test what I use. This file doesn't compile.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab} 
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\newtest{\ainfb}[2]{%
\cnttest{(#1)}{<=}{(#2)}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|}}
 \hline 
    19  &   21  
\\ \hline
\ifthenelse{\ainfb{:={[0,-1]}}{20}\and\ainfb{20}{:={[1,-1]}}}{T}{F} 
&               
\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}

\ifthenelse{\isodd{19}\and\isodd{21}}{True}{False}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to use the 'xintexpr' package for testing values from a suggestion of @jfbu, but I still have some problems. I give here an example for computing a percentile (here P_{25}). One can see that the good command, which gives a macro for this purpose is:

```
    \multicolumn{5}{m{8cm}|}{\xintifboolexpr{{:={[0,-1]}<=25} 'and' {25<=:={[1,-1]}}}
```

but this macro is refused by the program, and gives the code error

'! Undefined control sequence.\XINT_expr_unknown_variable'.

I've replaced ':={[1,-1]}' by 33.33, and then it compiles good. I've done this to show what I want to do with this program, but it's clear that it isn't a general solution. So that I've two problems

1/ How can I execute something like

'\xintifboolexpr{{:={[0,-1]}<=25} 'and' {25<=:={[1,-1]}}'?

2/ I've done the computation of the percentile in the next cell, because the computation which must be done by the command

'':={[0,-6]+(25-[0,-2])*([1,-6]-[0,-6])/([1,-2]-[0,-2])}''

in the cell of the test is not executed and is treated as characters... whenever I added @ . How can I do this ?

I give the tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}
 \STautoround{2}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|m{3.2cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}
 \hline 
@ \raggedright  Bounds  &1 & :={[-1,0]+ 5}& :={[-1,0]+ 5}
& :={[-1,0]+5}& :={[-1,0]+ 5}& :={[-1,0]+5} 
 \\\hline   
@  Intervals &  @(<<[0,-1]>>-<<[1,-1]>>(& @(<<[0,-1]>>-<<[1,-1]>>(& @(<<[0,-1]>>-<<[1,-1]>>(
&@(<<[0,-1]>>-<<[1,-1]>>(&@(<<[0,-1]>>-<<[1,-1]>>(& 
\\\hline 
@ Freq.&2&18&30&8&2&
\\\hline
@ Freq. Cum.&:={[0,-1]}&:={[0,-1]+[-1,0]}&:={[0,-1]+[-1,0]}&:={[0,-1]+[-1,0]}&:={[0,-1]+[-1,0]}&
\\\hline
@ Rel. Freq. Cum.&:={[0,-1]*100/[4,-1]}&:={[0,-1]*100/[3,-1]}&:={[0,-1]*100/[2,-1]}&:={[0,-1]*100/[1,-1]}&:={[0,-1]*100/[0,-1]}&
\\\hline
@\raggedright Percentile 
&
%%% The wanted command   %%%
%\multicolumn{5}{m{8cm}|}{\xintifboolexpr{{:={[0,-1]}<=25} 'and' {25<=:={[1,-1]}}}
\multicolumn{5}{m{8cm}|}{\xintifboolexpr{{:={[0,-1]}<=25} 'and' {25<=33.33}}
{$<<[0,-1]>>\leq 25\leq <<[1,-1]>>\Longrightarrow P_{25}\in(<<[0,-5]>>,<<[1,-5]>>($
}{FALSE}
}
\\\hline 
&
%%%\multicolumn{5}{m{8cm}|}{\xintifboolexpr{{:={[0,-1]}<=25} 'and' {25<=:={[1,-1]}}}
\multicolumn{5}{m{8cm}|}{\xintifboolexpr{{:={[0,-2]}<=25} 'and' {25<=33.33}}
{\raggedleft $ P_{25}=<<[0,-6]>>+\frac{25-<<[0,-2]>>}{<<[1,-2]>>-<<[0,-2]>>}(<<[1,-6]>>-<<[0,-6]>>)=$}{FALSE}
}
&:={[-5,-6]+(25-[-5,-2])*([-4,-6]-[-5,-6])/([-4,-2]-[-5,-2])}
\\\hline 
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

and how it compiles :
[image]

Comment: Well, the direct usage of `\isodd{19}` etc. yields true -- apparently, `\xifthen` is not aware of `spreadtab` syntax

Comment: It's the same effect if I use ifthen !

Comment: Well, I expected that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I had not read far enough into `spreadtab`'s doc.

Here is probably the better way (assuming you want to use `xifthen` booleans) to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab} 
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}\Huge
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|}}
 \hline 
    19  &   21  
\\ \hline
@\ifthenelse{\isodd{<<[0,-1]>>}\and\isodd{<<[1,-1]>>}}{True}{False}  
&%
\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

I wasn't sure `<<..>>` things could be used within braces, but they can.

output:

[image]

In a comment it was asked for a comparison test. You have predefined `"macro-functions"` `iflt`, `ifeq`, `ifgt` provided by `spreadtab`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab} 
%\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}\Huge
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}}
 \hline 
    19  &   20  & 21.5 & 37.8\\ 
\hline
 iflt([0,-1],[1,-1],[2,-1]+[3,-1],[2,-1]-[3,-1])&&&
\\ 
\hline
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

[image]

But if you want to print some textual contents depending on such a comparison test, it seems one has to revert to the technique with `@` and `<<`, `>>`. An example with `\xintifboolexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab} 
%\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\usepackage{xintexpr}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}\Huge
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}}
 \hline 
    19  &   20  & 21.5 & 37.8\\ 
\hline
@\xintifboolexpr{odd(<<[0,-1]>>) && odd(<<[1,-1]>>)}{T}{not both are odd}  
&@\xinttheiexpr[1] (odd(<<a1>>) 'and' odd(<<b1>>))?{<<c1>>+<<d1>>}{<<a1>>+<<b1>>}\relax
&@\xinttheiexpr[1] (odd(<<a1>>) 'or' odd(<<b1>>))?{<<c1>>+<<d1>>}{<<a1>>+<<b1>>}\relax
&
\\ 
\hline
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

[image]

In this example 
one cell uses  `@\xintifboolexpr {boolean expression}{True text}{False text}`.

Other cells make computations depending on boolean conditions using the `\xinttheiexpr[d] ... \relax` syntax (where `[d]` is number of digits to print on output after decimal mark). In the latter the naked `&` can not be used, and one uses `'and'` rather than `&&`. In the former example with `\xintifboolexpr` the `&&` is hidden by braces from the tabular and not confused with tabulations.

> Caveat: cells where numerical values are computed in this way via `@`
>   and some math engine are not considered "numeric cells" by
>   `spreadtab`. Hence a reference like `b2` will not work.
>
> Conclusion: for numerical conditional evaluations use as much as
>   possible `spreadtab`'s native `iflt`, `ifeq`, and `ifgt`, and make a
>   feature request to the package author for `ifodd` and `ifeven` tests
>   ...

---

earlier answer (**obsolete**).

Here is a work-around

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab} 
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{spreadtab}[\STsavecell\XXX{a1}\STsavecell\YYY{b1}]{{tabular}{|c|c|c|}}
 \hline 
    19  &   21  
\\ \hline
@\ifthenelse{\isodd{\XXX}\and\isodd{\YYY}}{True}{False}  
&% 
\\ \hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

[image]

I am currently reading `spreadtab` doc. It uses  `fp` as math engine. But the recognized functions for the `\FPeval` are:

```
 Known infix operations are
   +, -, *, /, ^ for add, sub, mul, div, pow
 Each other operation is a prefix one that needs 
 a (comma or colon seperated) list of subexpressions.
 Exception: The unary prefix operation - is not known! 
 (Use the function neg instead.)
 Example 1:
   With
     \edef\result{11}
   and
     \FPeval\result{round(root(2,sin(result + 2.5)):2)}
   or
     \FPeval{result}{round(root(2,sin(result + 2.5)):2)}
   \result becomes the value 0.90
```

I see no obvious way for "odd", even using "trunc", as `fp` handles anyhow fixed point numbers.

A more complete possible list of operations from `fp`'s README

```
 - fp-upn.sty:
     The following macros are public ones to be used in the document:
       \FPupn#1#2       % #1 := eval(#2) where eval evaluates the
                     upn-expression #2
 Known operations are:
   +,add,-,sub,*,mul,/,div,abs,neg,min,max,
   round,trunc,clip,e,exp,ln,pow,root,pi,sin,cos,
   sincos,tan,cot,tancot,arcsin,arccos,arcsincos,
   arctan,arccot,arctancot,pop,swap,copy
   where
     pop  removes the top element
     swap exchanges the first two elements
     copy copies the top element
```

It appears they make sense in `\FPeval` (apart I guess from `pop`, `swap`, `copy`).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didn't know that it depends from the test. If so, I must give my original test, which tests the order of two numbers. This file isn't accepted and gives the error message "Missing number,treated as zero..."
would you see my updated post please

Comment: I used my 'ainfb' test with your macro. It works for absolute reference \XXX but not for the relative one :={[-1,0]}. At all your macro is useful for me. Thanks

Comment: No it does not depend from the test. My answer has an additional `@` in the cell, as per `spreadtab`'s documentation. In your case you would use `@\ifthenelse{\ainfb{\XXX}{20}\and\ainfb{20}{\YYY}}{T}{F} `. And with the same `[\STsavecell\XXX{a1}\STsavecell\YYY{b1}]`.

Comment: Yes, it can not work with a spread tab reference whether relative or absolute. The `\XXX` is not a reference. It is a macro where spreadtab has been instructed to save a cell value.

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna see updated, better, answer. And if you have time, read `spreadtab`'s documentation `;-)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and update... I've read the doc but I'm not a very good programmer !

Comment: sorry for my earlier reply... I was answering another question on the site and skimming the `fp's README` and i stopped reading `spreadtab`'s doc as soon as I saw a way ... should have read one page farther ...

Comment: can you tell me on which pages can I find this on the doc... even a french doc if you prefer... this what I prefer too ! Many thanks

Comment: ah yes, there is French version of the doc (`texdoc -l spreadtab`) (see [ctan page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) ), and the info about `<<` and `>>` is in `3.6 Afficher la valeur d’une cellule`, on page 11 of doc version `v0.4c`. date `6 novembre 2014`.

Comment: Good morning. I have a problem with my data, which can be non-integer, and my test \ainfb is not useful in this case. How can I find a test of comparison of two non-integers numbers ?

Comment: `\usepackage{xintexpr}` and `@\xintifboolexpr{<<a1>c2>> 'and' (<<b3<e4>> 'or' odd(f2))}`` but I don't have time to check now. Besides `'and'` and `'or'` can also be coded `&&` and `||` respectively. No time to check now it does work in a `spreadtab`.

Comment: Thank you for your rapid answer. I'll see the doc of this packages.

Comment: In a first test, it seems very good. Thanks for this info of this very actual package 'xint', which dates from one month !, and seems very performant. Merci pour tout

Comment: only the latest update dates back from one month ago ... there are other options for comparing "real" numbers. I proposed `\xintifboolexpr` as I know it ...for numbers with at most 4+4 digits around decimal point there are low weight solutions with `\ifdim`.  `xintexpr` accepts scientific notation. But numeric cells in `spreadtab` from underlying `fp` are fixed point numbers, one can use `scitodec` wrapper provided by `spreadtab` on input ; but it uses `EE`. Currently xintexpr would only understand single `E` or `e`. Anyway if you test conditions on numeric cells, they will not have the `EE`.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll test it for my case and tell about improvements about it

Comment: Would you see my updated question please